# Calculating total number of days including previous periods depening on a condition in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to calculate the duration of sick leave for various employees. When there is less then 28 days between two periods of sick leave, they are considered as one period, and so the total duration of the sick leave is the current days of sick leave + the previous total of days of sick leave. I ended up with the following table:

```
Key-    Start date- End date-   Duration in days-   Duration of last sickleave- Less the 28 days-
0001    01-01-2015  14-01-2015  13  0   Yes
0001    03-03-2015  19-03-2015  16  13  No
0001    27-05-2015  28-05-2015  1   16  No
0001    18-08-2015  31-08-2015  13  1   No
0001    24-09-2015  05-10-2015  11  13  Yes
0001    21-10-2015  29-10-2015  8   11  Yes
0001    05-11-2015  09-11-2015  4   8   Yes
0001    07-12-2015  08-12-2015  1   4   No
0001    21-12-2015  28-12-2015  7   1   Yes
0001    12-01-2016  18-01-2016  6   7   Yes
0001    08-02-2016  29-02-2016  21  6   Yes
```

and I like to end up with this table:

```
Key-    Start date- End date-   Duration in days-   Duration of last sickleave- Less the 28 days-   Total number of days-
0001    01-01-2015  14-01-2015  13  0   Yes 13
0001    03-03-2015  19-03-2015  16  13  No  16
0001    27-05-2015  28-05-2015  1   16  No  1
0001    18-08-2015  31-08-2015  13  1   No  13
0001    24-09-2015  05-10-2015  11  13  Yes 24
0001    21-10-2015  29-10-2015  8   11  Yes 32
0001    05-11-2015  09-11-2015  4   8   Yes 36
0001    07-12-2015  08-12-2015  1   4   No  1
0001    21-12-2015  28-12-2015  7   1   Yes 8
0001    12-01-2016  18-01-2016  6   7   Yes 14
0001    08-02-2016  29-02-2016  21  6   Yes 35
```

How can I achieve this in SQL (using an Oracle database)? So when 'Less then 28 days' = 'Yes' AND 'Less then 28 days' on the previous row is 'Yes', Then 'Total number of days' = 'Total number of days' + 'Duration of last sickleave' else 'Total number of days'= 'Duration in days'.

Comment: 1. add the "create table ..." and "insert ..." for creating the testdata and 2. provide the sql you tried before

Comment: Hint: look at the LAG() analytic function.

Comment: @Boneist I tried the lag function ( i used it to get this table), but i have trouble with the self referencing (as in x = x + some value) i tried a case-statement, but i can't do 'Total number of days' = 'Total number of days' + 'Duration of last sickleave'

Comment: Why is total number of days for 24-09-2015 row = 11, rather than 11 + 13? That row is less than 28 days later than the previous row, so shouldn't it have the sum of the current + previous sick days?

Comment: @Boneist You are right, it should be 13 + 11, the row after that should be 13 + 11 + 8. I  will edit the example. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to add the previous sickness days to the current sickness duration, why not just do a rolling sum?

```
WITH           your_table AS (SELECT '0001' key_, to_date('01-01-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') start_date, to_date('14-01-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') end_date, 13 duration_in_days, 0 duration_of_last_sickleave, 'Yes' less_than_28_days FROM dual UNION ALL
                              SELECT '0001' key_, to_date('03-03-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') start_date, to_date('19-03-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') end_date, 16 duration_in_days, 13 duration_of_last_sickleave, 'No' less_than_28_days FROM dual UNION ALL
                              SELECT '0001' key_, to_date('27-05-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') start_date, to_date('28-05-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') end_date, 1 duration_in_days, 16 duration_of_last_sickleave, 'No' less_than_28_days FROM dual UNION ALL
                              SELECT '0001' key_, to_date('18-08-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') start_date, to_date('31-08-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') end_date, 13 duration_in_days, 1 duration_of_last_sickleave, 'No' less_than_28_days FROM dual UNION ALL
                              SELECT '0001' key_, to_date('24-09-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') start_date, to_date('05-10-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') end_date, 11 duration_in_days, 13 duration_of_last_sickleave, 'Yes' less_than_28_days FROM dual UNION ALL
                              SELECT '0001' key_, to_date('24-10-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') start_date, to_date('29-10-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') end_date, 8 duration_in_days, 11 duration_of_last_sickleave, 'Yes' less_than_28_days FROM dual UNION ALL
                              SELECT '0001' key_, to_date('05-11-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') start_date, to_date('09-11-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') end_date, 4 duration_in_days, 8 duration_of_last_sickleave, 'Yes' less_than_28_days FROM dual UNION ALL
                              SELECT '0001' key_, to_date('07-12-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') start_date, to_date('08-12-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') end_date, 1 duration_in_days, 4 duration_of_last_sickleave, 'No' less_than_28_days FROM dual UNION ALL
                              SELECT '0001' key_, to_date('21-12-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') start_date, to_date('28-12-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') end_date, 7 duration_in_days, 1 duration_of_last_sickleave, 'Yes' less_than_28_days FROM dual UNION ALL
                              SELECT '0001' key_, to_date('12-01-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') start_date, to_date('18-01-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') end_date, 6 duration_in_days, 7 duration_of_last_sickleave, 'Yes' less_than_28_days FROM dual UNION ALL
                              SELECT '0001' key_, to_date('08-02-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') start_date, to_date('29-03-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') end_date, 21 duration_in_days, 6 duration_of_last_sickleave, 'Yes' less_than_28_days FROM dual),
  identify_sickness_start AS (SELECT key_,
                                     start_date,
                                     end_date,
                                     duration_in_days,
                                     duration_of_last_sickleave,
                                     less_than_28_days,
                                     CASE WHEN start_date - LAG(end_date, 1, start_date - 30) OVER (PARTITION BY key_ ORDER BY start_date) >= 28 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END new_sickness_period
                              FROM   your_table),
     calc_sickness_groups AS (SELECT key_,
                                     start_date,
                                     end_date,
                                     duration_in_days,
                                     duration_of_last_sickleave,
                                     less_than_28_days,
                                     sum(new_sickness_period) OVER (PARTITION BY key_ ORDER BY start_date) grp
                              FROM   identify_sickness_start)
SELECT key_,
       start_date,
       end_date,
       duration_in_days,
       duration_of_last_sickleave,
       less_than_28_days,
       sum(duration_in_days) OVER (PARTITION BY key_, grp ORDER BY start_date) total_number_of_days
FROM   calc_sickness_groups
ORDER BY key_, start_date;

KEY_ START_DATE  END_DATE    DURATION_IN_DAYS DURATION_OF_LAST_SICKLEAVE LESS_THAN_28_DAYS TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_DAYS
---- ----------- ----------- ---------------- -------------------------- ----------------- --------------------
0001 01/01/2015  14/01/2015                13                          0 Yes                                 13
0001 03/03/2015  19/03/2015                16                         13 No                                  16
0001 27/05/2015  28/05/2015                 1                         16 No                                   1
0001 18/08/2015  31/08/2015                13                          1 No                                  13
0001 24/09/2015  05/10/2015                11                         13 Yes                                 24
0001 24/10/2015  29/10/2015                 8                         11 Yes                                 32
0001 05/11/2015  09/11/2015                 4                          8 Yes                                 36
0001 07/12/2015  08/12/2015                 1                          4 No                                   1
0001 21/12/2015  28/12/2015                 7                          1 Yes                                  8
0001 12/01/2016  18/01/2016                 6                          7 Yes                                 14
0001 08/02/2016  29/03/2016                21                          6 Yes                                 35
```

This works by first identifying the start of each sickness group (every time a new sickness period starts, output a 1; this means any time a row is <= 28 days after the previous row, we put a 1, otherwise a 0.

Then we can do a running sum across this column to work out the rows that are in the same sickness group.

Finally, we can then do a running total across the duration_in_days column for each set of sickness rows.

That means you no longer need to calculate the duration_of_last_sickleave and less_than_28_days columns (which I assume you're doing as part of a select statement, and not as part of the table?), as they are no longer necessary, at least not for the total days calculation!